# sed -n creating a new file with 'n' in the file extension

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Linux: RHEL6.10 Santiago

When I used `sed` with `-n` (which is used for silent mode), it works for the original file, **but** why it ended up creating a new file with no effect on the file and with the same name + suffixed a character `n` in the file's extension, see below - File: `/tmp/11.txtn`.

```
   -n, --quiet, --silent
          suppress automatic printing of pattern space
```

Here

```
[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ cat /tmp/11.txt 
arun nuka
arun snooka
arun chinga
arun patinga

[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ sed -i "/arun snooka/ d" /tmp/11.txt 
[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ cat /tmp/11.txt 
arun nuka
arun chinga
arun patinga

[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ sed -in "/arun chinga/ d" /tmp/11.txt 
[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ 
[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ cat /tmp/11.txt
arun nuka
arun patinga

[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ ls -l /tmp/11*
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser grpup1 24 Apr 25 16:19 /tmp/11.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser grpup1 36 Apr 25 16:19 /tmp/11.txtn
[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$ cat /tmp/11.txtn 
arun nuka
arun chinga
arun patinga

[myuser@rhel6linuxserverl15 a_folder]$
```

Comment: It will work if you reverse the `i` and `n` to `-ni`, but I recommend giving each their own dash.

Answer (score 4):

`-i` takes an optional parameter that denotes the extension of a backup file. Use `-n -i` or specify an extension (`-n -i~` is common).

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke `sed -in`, you are not passing the argument `-n`.  Instead, you are passing `n` as the suffix of the backup file to `-i`.

```
-i extension
         Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or
         partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
```

Comment: Yea, I knew -i was in place edit and I now see why it did it. I thought I can club those two together. Thanks. Actually `-n` is kind of redundant.